# get y value from c# chart series?

Tags: c#, charts

I have chart series:

```
Series[] tempSeries = new Series[sensorNum];    // Series to hold current/past temperature data for plotting, for each sensor
```

I add new points to them:

```
tempSeries[i].Points.AddXY(current_time, temp_F[i]);        // Add new temperature data to series
```

Now I want to convert the series to string to send it via socket.

The question is how to get Y value from the series?

I tried this:

```
private string sendAll() {
        string myMsg = "";
        double[,] lastTemp = new double[4, 1200];
        double[,] lastWind = new double[4, 1200];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1200; j++){
                try
                {
                    lastTemp[i, j] = tempSeries[i].Points[j].YValues[0];
                    myMsg += lastTemp[i, j] + " ";
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    lastTemp[i, j] = 0;
                    myMsg += 0 + " ";
                }
            }
        }
        myMsg += "; ";

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1200; j++)
            {
                try
                {
                    lastWind[i, j] = windSeries[i].Points[j].YValues[0];
                    myMsg += lastWind[i, j] + " ";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lastWind[i, j] = 0;
                    myMsg += 0 + " ";
                }
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(myMsg);

        return myMsg;
    }
```

But my program is freezing...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not the only problem with your code but you should never use string concatenation in loops (`myMsg += 0 + " ";` ...) cause strings are immutable. Use `StringBuilder` class instead. Like this:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        sb.Append("x");
    } 
    string x = sb.ToString();
```

Here is detailed info on why strings are immutable and what are the consequences of it:
http://en.morzel.net/post/2010/01/26/Why-strings-are-immutable-and-what-are-implications-of-it.aspx